# Unable to resove dependency issues

Tags: android-studio

please i want to know how I can fix
"Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.

Comment: explain more like when it happens

Comment: post your gradle file